# Jenkins docker plugin cloning on the host gives permission to root

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have my Jenkinsfile like this:

```
node {
     def image = docker.image('my-custom-image')
     image.inside("--user=root -e DOCKER_HOST=${env.DOCKER_HOST}") {
        stage('Install-tools') {
             withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credentials-id', passwordVariable: 'PASS', usernameVariable: 'USER')]) {
                  sh "git clone https://$USER:$PASS@myrepo/tools.git"
                  // sh "chown -R build:build tools/"
             }
        }
        stage('clone') { 
           checkout scm
        }
        stage('Deploy') { 
           sh "python3 -u deployscripts/deploy.py"
        }
     }

}
```

If I run it as it is above Jenkins fails because it cannot delete the workspace (return a big Java exception).

After some searching, I decided to uncomment the line `sh "chown -R build:build tools/"`. The directory `tools` that was owned by `root` is now owned by `build`. I no longer get the cannot delete workspace error.

What I fail to understand is:

My `git clone` is run inside `my-custom-image` docker container. The files are only inside my docker image (not using any `-v` here). The user `root` is root inside `my-custom-image`. Why does it create files owned by `root` on the host, preventing Jenkins from deleting the workspace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it create files owned by root on the host, preventing Jenkins from deleting the workspace ?

Becuase Jenkins auto-adds `-u <jenkins_user> -v ${env.WORKSPACE}:somedir -w somedir` to `docker run` arguments inside `image.inside`. Effectively, you are running `docker run` but kind of "inside" the workspace directory, which in most cases is more confusing than it should be. I find that just typing out `docker run` commands myself is more predictable.

Other CI/CD systems has solved this problem by working inside the container exclusively, like github-actions, or by sharing the workspace directory with other container that does the cloning and managing, like gitlab-cicd.